# validating bitbucket commit if it has a jira id

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks

Hi i need to validate bitbucket commit if it has a jira id. May be apply a pre receive webhook in bitbucket to check if there's a jira id.

Can some guide me. I think we can make a pre webhook - testing the bitbucket commit against a regular expression.

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: bitbucket cloud.. i am not able to use commit policy add on in cloud